# apply toggleclass function to element which has already one class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$("#Mpanel").on('click', '.ulmenu li', function() {

  var AppointType = $(this).text();

  if (AppointType == "R") {
    $("#spCsCharge").text("500 Rs");
    $(this).siblings(".Sappo").toggleClass();
    $(this).toggleClass("Sappo");
  } else if (AppointType == "T") {
    $("#spCsCharge").text("1000 Rs");
    $(this).siblings(".Sappo").toggleClass();
    $(this).toggleClass("Sappo Tappo");

  }

});
```

```css
.ulmenu li a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 11.5px 16px;
  background-color: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.ulmenu li.Tappo a {
  background-color: #F39090;
}
.ulmenu li.Sappo a {
  background-color: green;
}
.ulmenu li.ABappo a {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Mpanel" class="menu_simple">
  <ul class="ulmenu">
    <li><a href="#">R</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ABappo"><a href="#" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: none">X</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">R</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">R</a>
    </li>
    <li class="Tappo"><a href="#">T</a>
    </li>
    <li class="Tappo"><a href="#">T</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

constraint is 
**Select only one at a time.**

This is appointment application.
I have problem that when i select any "R" (for-regular) li this works nice.
But for "T"(for-tatkal) it create problem.
After un select of selected li "T" class ".Tappo" can not applies. It is look lies just default li.

What changes required in this code?
I don't know .please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line: `$(this).siblings(".Sappo").toggleClass();`. What you are doing here is this: Look for every sibling with a `Sappo`-class and toggle all classes. This is not what you want, because it will also remove the `Tappo` and `ABappo` classes.

In my example I use `$(this).siblings().removeClass(".Sappo");`. This means: Get every sibling and remove the class `Sappo` where it's active. Here is my optimized version:

```js
$("#Mpanel").on('click', '.ulmenu li', function() {

  var AppointType = $(this).children('a').text();
  switch (AppointType) {
    case "R":
      $("#spCsCharge").text("500 Rs");
      break;
    case "T":
      $("#spCsCharge").text("1000 Rs");
      break;
  }

  $(this).siblings().removeClass("Sappo");
  $(this).toggleClass("Sappo");
});
```

```css
.ulmenu li a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 11.5px 16px;
  background-color: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.ulmenu li.Tappo a { background-color: #F39090; }
.ulmenu li.Sappo a { background-color: green; }
.ulmenu li.ABappo a { background-color: #ccc; }
#spCsCharge { clear: both; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Mpanel" class="menu_simple">
  <ul class="ulmenu">
    <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
    <li class="ABappo"><a href="#" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: none">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
    <li class="Tappo"><a href="#">T</a></li>
    <li class="Tappo"><a href="#">T</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="spCsCharge"></div>
```

Comment: Yes. This is OP's expectation. But the selected "T" li will have two background color.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @JohnR This doesn't really matter. If two selectors have the same priority the one which is defined last in the CSS code is the one that takes priority. So as long as you define `.Sappo` under `.Tappo` and `.ABappo` in the CSS code, `.Sappo` will take priority and thus the boxes will be green.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the text of `a` and not `.li`.

Change `var AppointType = $(this).text();` to `var AppointType = $(this).find('a').text();`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#Mpanel").on('click', '.ulmenu li', function() {

    var AppointType = $(this).find('a').text();

    if (AppointType == "R") {
      $("#spCsCharge").text("500 Rs");
      $(this).toggleClass("Sappo");
    } else if (AppointType == "T") {
      $("#spCsCharge").text("1000 Rs");
      $(this).toggleClass("Sappo");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ulmenu li a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 11.5px 16px;
  background-color: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.ulmenu li.Tappo a {
  background-color: #F39090;
}
.ulmenu li.Sappo a {
  background-color: green;
}
.ulmenu li.ABappo a {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Mpanel" class="menu_simple">
  <ul class="ulmenu">
    <li><a href="#">R</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ABappo"><a href="#" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: none">X</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">R</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">R</a>
    </li>
    <li class="Tappo"><a href="#">T</a>
    </li>
    <li class="Tappo"><a href="#">T</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="spCsCharge" style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: My problem is i want to set original class after unselect li

Comment: $(this).toggleClass("Sappo Tappo");

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $("#Mpanel").on('click', '.ulmenu li', function() {

        var AppointType = $(this).text();

        if (AppointType == "R") {
            $("#spCsCharge").text("500 Rs");
        } else if (AppointType == "T") {
            $("#spCsCharge").text("1000 Rs");
        }
            $(this).siblings(".tClass.Sappo").addClass('Tappo').removeClass('Sappo');
            $(this).siblings(".rClass.Sappo").removeClass('Sappo');
            $(this).toggleClass("Sappo");

    });
```

```css
.ulmenu li a {
                float: left;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
                padding: 11.5px 16px;
                background-color: #808080;
                border: 1px solid #fff;
     }
    .ulmenu li.Tappo a {
        background-color: #F39090;
    }

    .ulmenu li.Sappo a {
        background-color: green;
    }

    .ulmenu li.ABappo a {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="Mpanel" class="menu_simple">
        <ul class="ulmenu">
            <li class="rClass"><a href="#">R</a></li>
            <li class="ABappo"><a href="#" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: none">X</a></li>
            <li class="rClass"><a href="#">R</a></li>
            <li class="rClass"><a href="#">R</a></li>
            <li class="Tappo tClass"><a href="#">T</a></li>
            <li class="Tappo tClass"><a href="#">T</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I have added 2 classes in HTML and modified JS accordingly, Please let me know if this is what is expected